# Statistically increase mean difference between two data sets?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-data

A dataset will be used to train a binary classification model. For better understanding/visualization, the data set was divided into 2:

- one set with all the rows that result in prediction value of 1
- another set with all the rows that result in prediction value of 0

Comparing both datasets, there are small, but expected differences in many of the features. For example, a lower mean or median.

Is there a sound way to statistically enhance the data to make the differences more visible to a model?
For example, going from this small difference in the mean (the red dotted line):
[image]

To something where the mean difference is much more pronounced? (Please excuse the crudeness of the drawing)

[image]

I've thought about applying a logarithmic transformation, but since my data behavior is not exponential, I wanted to corroborate any possible approaches beforehand with the community.

Let me know if my question needs clarification.

Comment: Why all this? Tell us what is your ultimate goal!

Comment: The kind of "pronouncing more" that your images show apparently relies on treating the two classes differently. Obviously for new data with unknown class this cannot be done. There may be transformations that allow more precise classification, but this can only be found out by experiments in connection with a classification method. I'm not sure whether your data are one-dimensional, but if they are and what you show is all you have, I'm not optimistic. Whatever transformation you use, there will always only be five  possible values, if I interpret your images correctly.

Comment: @https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen To increase precision and recall of the binary classification model. The difference between classes as of now gives OK performance but if I could increase the differentiation I would get better performance